# Stuck trying to layout my fields

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS but I am trying to create this layout:

[image: Layout]

I have tried to have a wack at this, and here is the code I have:

http://jsfiddle.net/cskQ8/

Now, I know this is basic, but what am I doing wrong?

P.s I want this to cope with a field of any height (i.e very tall)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.fieldwrapper{display:inline-block}`

As div is block element, it is getting displayed in the next row so make it inline block then it flows in the same row.

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cskQ8/1/)

---

In simple form you can remove div around input and write like below

```
    <div class="r6 dc3 ts2 p4">
    <label field_id="None" for="sender">Sender email address</label>
    <input class="field r2 lft dc1 tc5 ts3" placeholder="Email" type="text" value="">
    </div>​

.lft { float: left; }
ul, li { list-style-type: none; }
.ts3 { font-size: 15px; }
.dc3 { background-color: #808080; }
.tc5 { color: #333333; }
.p4 { padding: 4px; }
.r2 { border-radius: 2px; -moz-border-radius: 2px; -webkit-border-radius: 2px; }
.r6 { border-radius: 6px; -moz-border-radius: 6px; -webkit-border-radius: 6px; overflow:auto}
.field { line-height:27px; font-family:arial, sans-serif; border-color: #d9d9d9; border-top:solid 1px #c0c0c0; padding-left:5px; margin-right: 15px; width:250px; }
label{float:left; padding-right:15px}
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/cskQ8/11/

Answer (score 1):

You want a "row" wrapper around the label and the field.

You then float the label left and the field right.

To clear the floats set the "row" to `overflow: hidden;`

```
.formRow {
    background: #eee;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 5px 5% 5px 5%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.formRow label {
    float: left;
}   

.formRow .field{
    float: right;
} 

<div class="formRow">
    <label field_id="None" for="sender">Sender email address</label>
    <input class="field r2 lft dc1 tc5 ts3" placeholder="Email" type="text" value="">
</div>
```

This is a very basic example. You can play around with the widths and heights here - http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/cskQ8/8/

Answer (score 0):

The given examples use `inline-block`. However, your image shows that the text is vertically centered. You can use `display: table-cell` for that.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cskQ8/12/

Answer (score 0):

try this, may be u need to edit on the size, padding and colors....

css =>

```
@charset "utf-8";

    body{
       margin:auto;/*for aligning*/
       padding:0; /*for squeezing in txt*/
       height:100%; /*100% used to fill windows height*/
       behaviour:url(csshover.htc);

    }

    .header{
       margin:auto;/*for aligning*/
       padding:5px;
       height:30px;
       width:100%;
       background-color:#808080;
    }
    .header .holder{
        margin:auto;
       padding:0;
       height:30px;
       width:1018px;
       background-color:#333333;
    }

    .lft {
        float: left; 
    }

    ul, li {
        list-style-type: none; 
    }

    .tc5 {
        color:black;
    }



    .r2 {
        border-radius: 2px; 
        -moz-border-radius: 2px; 
        -webkit-border-radius: 2px; 
    }



    .field {
         line-height:27px; 
         font-family:arial, sans-serif; 
         border-color: blue; 
         border-top:solid 1px #c0c0c0; 
         padding-left:5px; 
         margin-right: 15px; 
         width:250px; 
    }
```

html =>

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link href="new.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
</head>    
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="holder">
            <label field_id="None" for="sender"align="left">Sender email address</label>
            <input class="field r2 lft tc5 " placeholder="Email" type="text" value="">
            <div class="fieldwrapper">   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```